# Set alt tag to more than 1000 images

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have an html file with more than 1000 images/links.
I need to find an efficient way to set the alt tag of each image to the Title of the targeted link.
I know some php but I thought that JavaScript would be more efficient. What do you suggest?
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking to do this once and replace the source file or to do it repeatedly on the fly when the page is requested?

Comment: you need to modify html text, otherwise (i.e. if you set alt parameter with javascript) these ALTs won't be visible for search engines

Comment: Why can't this be done when you are building the original HTML? It doesn't make any sense, unless you simply can't be bothered to write the alt attributes? Are you building the HTML with PHP?

Comment: It depends of your html structure. If it's semantic and clear it can be faster. Post some code for us to see what can be done.

Comment: Note that the "alt" tag is intended to be used to hold a *description* of the image, and *not* a "title" to be shown as a flyover.  For that, you want the "title" attribute.

Comment: @WesleyMurch, the file is already built and I didn't make it... I just have to "fix" it.

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery:

```
$('a img').each(function(i, img) {
    var title = img.parent('a').attr('title');
    img.attr('alt', title);
});
```

get all `img` tags inside an `a`, then set the img's alt attribute to be equal to its parent's `a` title.

Not tested, will probably sell your dog into slavery, YMMV, etc...